# Как организовать подсчет того, сколько раз сработал метод

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу организовать визуализацию процесса парсинга в моем приложении, мне нужно  как-то отображать, сколько страниц было спарсено. Отметкой о том, что страница спарсена, будет то, что страница добавлена в основной массив готовых страниц.  Сложность в том, что всё это в [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) (буду отображать прогрессбар) и сам метод выполняется асинхронно. И мне нужно, как-то в реальном времени видеть изменения количества спарсенных страниц. Упрощено, метод который парсит выглядит так.

```
public async Task ParssGo()
{                            
    var mass = cr.Massurls(readyStrings); // в массиве содержатся адреса всех страниц для парсинга

    int andProgress=mass.Length; // конечное значение для прогресбара
    andProgress = MyProperty2;

    int startProgress = 0;// начальное значение прогрессбара
    startProgress = MyProperty1;

    // парсим и добавляем в массив спарсенных страниц
    foreach (var item in mass)
    {                   
        Big.AddRange(await pr.GetResumme(item)); // Big есть массив спарсенных страниц
        startProgress++;
    }    
}
```

Вопрос, как мне правильно получить счетчик спарсенных страниц в реальном времени.

Comment: @4per да вы правы, подправил

Comment: @Bulson Спасибо за ответ, оно и не работает как раз по этой причине, вопрос как мне дождаться окончания работы этого метода?

Comment: @Bulson, вы путаете человека. Прогресс бар не добежит мгновенно до конца, т.к. на каждой итерации цикла при парсинге очередного url стоит `await`. А то, что у него матрешка вида `Big.AddRange(await pr.GetResumme(item));` - это лишь придирка к стилю написания кода, но не к логике его работы.

Comment: @Bulson, а вы пробовали это проверить? https://dotnetfiddle.net/8IksU5

Comment: @Groxan, да, спасибо, вы правы, а я нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что вы хотите получить, делается с помощью Binding'a.

**Binding** - это когда мы привязываем нужные параметры контролов (например, `ProgressBar.Value`) к нужным свойствам, с которыми мы будем работать в коде (например, `startProgress`). Когда привязанное свойство меняется, все связанные контролы уведомляются и перерисовываться.

Приведу **пример**, как это сделать:

```
//Для начала, унаследуем INotifyPropertyChanged, чтобы Binding работал
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Этот event мы будем дергать каждый раз, когда нужно перерисовать ProgressBar
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //Создадим свойство, которое будет отвечать за текущее значение ProgressBar
    int _CurrentProgress = 0;
    public int CurrentProgress
    {
        get => _CurrentProgress;
        set
        {
            if (_CurrentProgress != value)
            {
                _CurrentProgress = value;
                //Когда свойство меняется, будем дергать наш event
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentProgress)));
            }
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Также добавим вот это, чтобы Binding работал
        DataContext = this;
    }

    //...//
}
```

Теперь в xaml привяжем свойство `CurrentProgress` к нашему `ProgressBar`:

```
<ProgressBar Maximum="1024" Value="{Binding Path=CurrentProgress}"/>
```

И теперь мы можем просто изменять `CurrentProgress`, и `ProgressBar` будет автоматически обновляться:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //...//

    public async Task ParssGo()
    {
        CurrentProgress = 256;
    }
}
```

---

> Сложность в том что все это в wpf

P.S. Это не сложность, а как раз наоборот =) Надо просто привыкнуть к биндингу.

---

### Пример биндинга с моделью

Пусть модель выглядит так:

```
public class MyParsingModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    int _CurrentProgress = 0;
    public int CurrentProgress
    {
        get => _CurrentProgress;
        set
        {
            if (_CurrentProgress != value)
            {
                _CurrentProgress = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentProgress)));
            }
        }
    }

    int _MaxProgress = 100;
    public int MaxProgress
    {
        get => _MaxProgress;
        set
        {
            if (_MaxProgress != value)
            {
                _MaxProgress = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MaxProgress)));
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task Parse()
    {
        MaxProgress = 100;
        CurrentProgress = 0;

        while (CurrentProgress++ < MaxProgress)
            await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}
```

Тогда `MainWindow` будет таким:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MyParsingModel MyModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyModel = new MyParsingModel();
        DataContext = this;

        //Важный момент: если MyModel будет инициализироваться
        //или изменяться после предыдущей строчки, то, чтобы окно 
        //понимало, что MyModel изменился, нужно MainWindow также
        //наследовать от INotifyPropertyChanged, а свойство MyModel
        //делать по аналогии со свойствами в модели (чтобы при 
        //изменении дергался event). Если же MyModel инициализируется
        //один раз и в самом начале, то достаточно того, как написано.
    }
}
```

А в xaml вот так:

```
<ProgressBar Maximum="{Binding Path=MyModel.MaxProgress}" 
                Value="{Binding Path=MyModel.CurrentProgress}" />
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, это важная часть вопроса, но без того ка мне посчитать значения для прогресс бара будет сложно.

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch, Так у вас и так реализован правильный расчет значения для прогресс бара: есть массив с url'ами `mass`, есть цикл `foreach(var item in mass)`, где вы проходите по всем url'ам и на каждой итерации парсите один url `await pr.GetResumme(item)`, добавляете результат в свое хранилище `Big.AddRange` и инкрементируете прогресс бар `startProgress++`. Не вижу, что здесь неправильного =) Вам нужно из своей функции убрать локальные переменные `andProgress` и `startProgress` и вместо них работать с глобальными свойствами, которые сбиндите с прогресс баром.

Comment: Этот класс, где этот метод,  у меня лежит в логике Model.  мне нужно создать свойства публичные, и потом через них связаться уже во ViewModel? я так пробовал, но что то не сработало

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch, добавил пример с моделью